# setting up STM32 ADC interrupt in asm

Tags: assembly, stm32

I'm programming stm32 in assembly, I need to know how to handle interrupts for adc in Assembler
for example, in C I know that

```
SET_BIT(ADC1->CR1, ADC_CR1_EOCIE);      // enable interrupt generation
NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);               // allow interrupt in NVIC

void ADC_IRQHandler()
{
    
}
```

how do I do write this in  assembler ,any ideas ?

Comment: Have you read the technical reference manual for the chip, and do you have a decent understanding of ARM assembly? These lines translate extremely closely to assembly instruction/labels.